# Marking up 2D polygon perimeter on an image

Tags: 2d, javascript, collider

I'm working on a 2D game in JavaScript using the Web canvas. I plan to use AABB proximity detection and then point, line and polygon on polygon collision detection.

Which means I need to define polygon perimeters for each of my potentially colliding objects. I have to come up with a list of pivot-point-relative coordinates for each vertex on the perimeter of the object's sprite.

This is a tedious and laborious task to do manually, and it seems like it's something that lots and lots of game developers must have had to do many many times.

What is a more efficient workflow for marking up collision polygons on an image or sprite?

Comment: Software & tool recommendations are not considered on-topic on this particular exchange (the "tools" tag is about developing your own tools). You can try the Software Recommendations StackExchange if you want links to existing software, or, if you're trying to build such a tool yourself, edit your question to describe what kind of help you need to complete it.

Comment: Thanks for editing rather than closing. Why do we need such a rule? Isn't the purpose of SO gamedev to facilitate devs helping each other? A forum less popular or less focused on game dev would be less likely to be of help. Communities flourish better in the absence of purpose defeating rules. I've found great answers to requests for software recommendations on SO Many times over the years, despite that rule. SO isn't popular because of rules like that, it's popular because of the look and feel and the vote tracking and the way the most voted up answers float up.

Comment: Devs can help each other in lots of different ways. Some of those ways are a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format, and some are better served by other sites' formats. Questions asking for particular tools are one of those topics. They tend to generate open-ended lists of links rather than high-quality self-contained solutions. If you've ever seen an emacs vs vim flamewar, you know devs have very strong opinions about tools that often don't lead to a "best" answer rising to the top constructively. Tool links are also prone to becoming outdated, as versions change & new tools release.

Comment: We've [discussed this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good) a [few times](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1082/39518) on [Meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/). [Most recently here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2661/39518), where I argued that most any "what program has this feature?" question can be addressed more constructively as "how do I solve this problem?"

Comment: I guess I can see preferring to avoid having what amounts to a vim vs emacs flamewar on SO. You wouldn't really get a "best" answer out of that. But you would get a good feel for the most cogent reasons people prefer each, which is helpful to someone posing the question.The problem with not having them on SO is that they need to be had somewhere, and if not on SO then where? SO has become such an industry icon that it seems like other sites just aren't active enough to produce any results anytime soon.

Comment: Generally we recommend more informal discussion forums or [chat] for polling what software other devs recommend.